# Rust expected type found struct

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I've got the following code:

```rust
use actix_service::Service;
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer, Responder};

use actix_router::{Path, Url};
use actix_web::dev::{ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse};
use actix_web::error::ResponseError;
use actix_web::{http, http::StatusCode, Error, HttpRequest, HttpResponse};

async fn greet(req: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
    let name = req.match_info().get("name").unwrap_or("World");
    format!("Hello {}!", &name)
}

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        let app = App::new()
            .wrap_fn(|req, srv| {
                let passed: bool;

                // change to false to simulate a failed check
                let check = true;

                if *&req.path().contains("/item/") {
                    passed = check;
                } else {
                    passed = true;
                }

                let fresh_result = match passed {
                    true => {
                        let fut = srv.call(req);
                        Box::pin(async {
                            let result = fut.await?;
                            Ok(result)
                        })
                    }
                    false => Box::pin(async {
                        let result = req.into_response(
                            HttpResponse::Found()
                                .header(http::header::LOCATION, "/login")
                                .finish()
                                .into_body(),
                        );
                        Ok(result)
                    }),
                };
                async {
                    let last_outcome = fresh_result.await?;
                    Ok(last_outcome)
                }
            })
            .route("/", web::get().to(greet));
        return app;
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8000")?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
110 |                         let fresh_result = match passed {
    |    ________________________________________-
111 |   |                         true => {
112 |   |                             let fut = srv.call(req);
113 |   |                             Box::pin(
    |  _|_____________________________-
114 | | |                                 async {
115 | | |                             let result = fut.await?;
116 | | |                             Ok(result)
117 | | |                             }
118 | | |                             )
    | |_|_____________________________- this is found to be of type `std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<impl core::future::future::Future>>`
...     |
121 | / |                             Box::pin(
122 | | |                             async {
123 | | |                             let result = req.into_response(
124 | | |                                 HttpResponse::Found()
...   | |
129 | | |                             }
130 | | |                             )
    | |_|_____________________________^ expected generator, found a different generator
131 |   |                         }
132 |   |                     };
    |   |_____________________- `match` arms have incompatible types
    | 
   ::: /Users/maxwellflitton/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/future/mod.rs:55:43
    |
55  |     pub const fn from_generator<T>(gen: T) -> impl Future<Output = T::Return>
    |                                               ------------------------------- the found opaque type
    |
    = note: expected type `std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<impl core::future::future::Future>>` (generator)
             found struct `std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<impl core::future::future::Future>>` (generator)
```

I am completely stuck on this. I don't know how to ensure it's a type. If there is no match statement and there is just one async block then it all runs fine. This is for middleware in an Actix-web server. I am trying to redirect the viewer if credentials are not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre].

Comment: when your question include over 9000 indentation spaces, you should feel this is not good.

Comment: IIRC async block behave like closures, meaning every async block is its own type unless you type-erase it. So your two branches do return future-implementing types but they're *different* types, like returning an `impl Display` and one branch returns a `String` while the other returns an `u32`does not work unless you erase behind a `Box<dyn Display>`. You don't provide a reproducible code but try to type your function as returning sth like `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>` (probably needs [some more bounds](https://github.com/dtolnay/async-trait#explanation)).

Comment: @Masklinn I have edited it so there's a minimal amount of code to run the entire app thanks

Comment: @trentci I have edited it so there's a minimal amount of code to run the entire app thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Box::pin` to create the boxed futures,
but Rust still thinks you want the `impl Future<...>` version (meaning the future is boxed to the heap, but doesn't use dynamic dispatch).

This is why the type in the error is `Pin<Box<impl Future<...>>>`, and because any two `impl Future<...>`s are of different types, you get the `expected/found` error.

You need to tell Rust you are interested in dynamic dispatch (because you have two different futures that can be stored in the `Box`, and which one really is stored there can only be known at runtime), for example by explicitly specifying the return type like this:

```
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::future::Future;

let fresh_result: Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=_>>> = match passed {
    // ...
}
```

Now you will get a new error about `cannot infer type for type parameter E` which can be resolved by specifying the `Output` of the future as well,
so the new line should be:

```
let fresh_result: Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<ServiceResponse, Error>>>> = match passed {
    // ...
}
```

which will compile successfully!

Comment: Dude this is amazing! Thanks for this